# conditional formatting based on two cells in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to do conditional formatting [in a google spreadsheet] on a row based on either a text cell in column a, or ideally, a combination of a and b.   ["Hot lead" + "large opp"]

My header rows are at the top, so key data starts at a3.

Answer (score 0):

function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1'), 
      values = s.getRange('A3:B').getValues(), 
      x, rowColors = [], color, colors = [], numCols = 3;

for (var row = 0, len = values.length; row < len; row++) {
    if (values[row][0] === 'Hot lead' && values[row][1] === 'large opp') color = 'Red';
    else color = 'White';
    for (x = 0; x < numCols; x++ ) rowColors.push(color);
    colors.push(rowColors);
    rowColors = [];
  }

s.getRange('A3').offset(0,0,colors.length, numCols).setBackgroundColors(colors);
}